# Is there a way to use a QTcpSocket with an existing socket?

Tags: c++, qt4

I use a library that returns a handle to a socket. Once I have that handle, I need to read and write from it. I'd rather use QTcpSocket as it's easier than using read()/write(). Is there a way to use QTcpSocket with an already opened socket rather than have QTcpSocket open the socket?

Comment: This `setSocketDescriptor`method may be relevant , http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#setSocketDescriptor

Comment: You might also have a look at the QSocketNotifier class as a possible alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use QTcpSocket with an exisiting socket descriptor :

```
QTcpSocket* socket = new QTcpSocket();
socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDesc); // socketDesc is a pointer of  type   qintptr
```

and now you can read and write into socket

Comment: That's exactly what I want but it isn't working. My problem must be elsewhere.